# Finding a shortest path within a d3.js network graph using an algorithm library

Tags: javascript, d3.js, path-finding

I would like to use https://github.com/qiao/PathFinding.js with a d3.js network graph to test various algorithms for finding a shortest path.

d3 edges data structure for example:

```
[{"source":1,"target":3},{"source":3,"target":4},{"source":3,"target":6}, ...]
```

[image: network graph]

I would like to calculate the shortest path from eg. node 1 to node 10.

Is it possible to use mentioned PathFinding library for graphs instead of grids at all? If it is possible could you explain how it can be done please ?

Comment: PathFinding expects an explicit 2D structure indicating "walls" vs walkable space. d3 graphs are not explicitly mapped to 2D points. You need to provide more information about what kind of correspondence you want.

Comment: I ended up using _Cytoscape.js_ (A*) and _JSNetworkX_ (BFS) for finding a shortest path in a network graph.

Comment: Looking for the same thing [Cytoscape.js](http://js.cytoscape.org/) was a very usefull tool and previous comment lead me to it. Thanks!

Comment: By now i am using sigma.js v1 with astar plugin